# What are my mistakes by using sensors?

Tags: sensors, pressure

I slowly make my first tries with using sensors. And i want to show the actual air pressure (My smartphone defently have a airpressuresensor.)

I look at some code and copy some code, and build the app. Now it doesnt work, and I dont know why. Does sensors need sth. in the manifest or so?
There are no errorcodes, just a applicationcrash...

the evil line seems to be, because if I build a try and catch around the app dont crash, but nothing happends. : sMgr.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public Handler handler = new Handler();
public double a;
SensorManager sMgr;
Sensor sensor;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sMgr = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> sensors = sMgr.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);
    if(sensors.size() > 0) {


        sensor = sensors.get(0);
            sMgr.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


    }



}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float presure = event.values[0];
    Log.d("PressureSens", ""+presure);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText(""+ presure);
}
```

Comment: You should give more contextual information in the title, description and keywords about what you are doing so people may understand what it is about straightaway: programming language? device type?

Comment: If it's crashing then learn how to read the stack trace in the log, having trouble then post the log.  You should be able to get back to a line in your code which should give you a clue as to the error.